# System permissions on vendor partition

Tags: android, system, android-source, vendor, android.mk

I have started to work on AOSP and I have a couple of applications that I do not to update when I update my OS. I tried using the vendor partition and flashing my specified appilcations on the vendor partition which built successfully. During run time the application crashed since it needs some system level permissions. Is there any way I can have a system app on the vendor partition ?

Answer (score 0):

Have this in your manifest

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

Then using Android Studio menu Build > Build APK(s). Then take that apk and sign with system signature using pek and pk8 files. Then push them in /vendor/app
OR Build the app using AOSP tree. Push that apk from out//vendor/app/ .

Hope this helps.